# Removing and replacing values in List of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have List something like below:

```
[[{
        'canBeAdded' : True,
        'categories' : ['Diving', 'Sports'],
        'relevanceRank' : 1,
        'rankSource' : 'NONE',
        'value' : 1.0,
        'canBeRemoved' : True,
        'displayStartDate' : '2013-02-10T05:00:00Z',
        'filterTags' : [],
        'relevanceScore' : -1.0,
    }
], [{
        'canBeAdded' : True,
        'categories' : ['Bucket', 'Sports'],
        'relevanceRank' : 1,
        'rankSource' : 'NONE',
        'value' : 1.0,
        'canBeRemoved' : True,
        'displayStartDate' : '2013-02-10T05:00:00Z',
        'filterTags' : [],
        'relevanceScore' : -1.0,
    }
]]
```

I want to perform below actions:

- Remove 'rankSource' : 'NONE' element from the lists
- Update 'canBeAddedToCard' element to False
- update 'relevanceRank' and 'relevanceScore' element to 0

Comment: OK. Let us know how you get on with that.

Comment: Just what is your question?

Comment: There is no other way than iterate over it. List comprehension would make it somewhat more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Start reading: 
https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/IntroductionToPythonSolutions.html

Try this:

```
LL =  [[{
        'canBeAdded' : True,
        'categories' : ['Diving', 'Sports'],
        'relevanceRank' : 1,
        'rankSource' : 'NONE',
        'value' : 1.0,
        'canBeRemoved' : True,
        'displayStartDate' : '2013-02-10T05:00:00Z',
        'filterTags' : [],
        'relevanceScore' : -1.0,
    }
], [{
        'canBeAdded' : True,
        'categories' : ['Bucket', 'Sports'],
        'relevanceRank' : 1,
        'rankSource' : 'NONE',
        'value' : 1.0,
        'canBeRemoved' : True,
        'displayStartDate' : '2013-02-10T05:00:00Z',
        'filterTags' : [],
        'relevanceScore' : -1.0,
    }
]]

for i, row in enumerate(LL):
    LL[i][0]['relevanceRank']    = 0
    LL[i][0]['relevanceScore']   = 0
    LL[i][0]['canBeAddedToCard'] = False
    del LL[i][0]['rankSource']      

 #   [[{'canBeAdded': True,
 #      'canBeAddedToCard': False,
 #      'canBeRemoved': True,
 #      'categories': ['Diving', 'Sports'],
 #      'displayStartDate': '2013-02-10T05:00:00Z',
 #      'filterTags': [],
 #      'relevanceRank': 0,
 #      'relevanceScore': 0,
 #      'value': 1.0}],
 #    [{'canBeAdded': True,
 #      'canBeAddedToCard': False,
 #      'canBeRemoved': True,
 #      'categories': ['Bucket', 'Sports'],
 #      'displayStartDate': '2013-02-10T05:00:00Z',
 #      'filterTags': [],
 #      'relevanceRank': 0,
 #      'relevanceScore': 0,
 #      'value': 1.0}]]
```